# N-1 chi-square analysis/contingency tables that also accounts for a 3 option categorical variable in R?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, biostatistics

I do not even know if such a test exists, although, ideally, it does. I want to run a comparison of proportions test as seen [here](https://www.medcalc.org/calc/comparison_of_proportions.php), that adjusts for a 3 part categorical variable (either "A","B", or "C") as well. The link is just an example - what it basically does is run a chi-square test (I think) based on a ratio and sample sizes and determines the statistical significance of the difference between ratios in groups [comparison of proportions, as it is called]. What would be the proper statistical test to look into running to determine the statistical significance in the comparison of proportions that also takes into account that categorical variable?

Thanks. I hope this isn't a terrible/obvious question.

Comment: Please add whatever information is necessary to understand & answer your question into the question itself. People aren't going to want to have to navigate elsewhere & read through something just so they can answer your question for you. Moreover, we want these threads to remain intelligible even after the link goes dead. A small dataset to illustrate your situation would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is stratify your sample based on your categorical variable and then compute a Mantel-Haenszel Odds Ratio.